# How to literaly turn a string value into a value of a byte?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, byte

I have a list of strings with values like these:

```
example[0] = "0xFF";
example[1] = "0xA8";
```

What I'm trying to do is literally set those values as values of bytes, like:

```
byte x = Convert.ToByte(example[0]);
byte y = Convert.ToByte(example[1]);
```

Sooo, how can I do it?

Note: I literally need the byte variable contains "0xFF" as its value, for example...

Answer (score 3):

just use `ToByte` with the appropriate *Base*. `ToByte` will convert both values `FF` and literals `0xFF`, so there is no need to remove the `0x`

```
var byte = Convert.ToByte(hex, 16)
```

or

```
var hexes = new string[] { "0xFF", "0xA8"};
var results = hexes.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
                   .ToArray();

foreach (var item in results)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
255
168
```

---

**Update**

> but there's some way to convert those strings keeping the Hex
>   structure? You know: `byte x = 0xFF`;

```
var hexes = new string[] { "0xFF", "0xA8" };
var results = hexes.Select(x => $"byte {Convert.ToByte(x, 16)} = {x}")
                   .ToArray();

foreach (var item in results)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
byte 255 = 0xFF
byte 168 = 0xA8
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8AuVPb)

---

**Additional Resources**

[ToByte(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_)

> Converts the string representation of a number **in a specified base** to
>   an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks for the answer, but, actually, I need the output be exactly the same thing as the string. This way I have, for example, "255" instead "0xFF"... any idea? haha

Comment: @IgorHenriques this does convert hex literals to bytes, https://dotnetfiddle.net/NzgRSx

Comment: Yep. I tested it out, but there's some way to convert those strings keeping the Hex structure? You know: `byte x = 0xFF;`

Comment: Hahaha sorry :( but it returns a string... I tried to parse anyway to my list and it shows me the classical `Input string was not in a correct format`. Why is not possible just set easily the value "0xFF" if we can do this manually declaring the variable...

Comment: @IgorHenriques it is probably very easy, the hard part is trying to work out what you actually want. can you update your question with as much information as you can, as this could go around in circles for ever

Comment: Michael, I'm trying to write those hex in a .exe which I can only do this being a byte variable. Therefore, strings doesnt help me :/

I don't know exactly how to be more clear, but lets say I want to create a byte with this syntax: `byte x = 0xFF` at runtime.